# c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\desktop unavaliable

Tags: windows-7, boot

Last night I shut down my computer as normal.

Today when I logged in it took much longer than usual and I got this error.

`C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\desktop refers to a location that is unavailable. It could be on a hard drive on this computer.or on a network. Check to make sure that the disk is properly inserted, or that you are connected to the Internet or your network and then try again. If it still cannot be located the information might have been moved to a different location.`

The screen looked like an old win2000 theme, all icons on the screen was blank and the start menu had no programs in it.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [web is full of suggestions](http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=config+system+profile+desktop) how to deal with this problem, ranging from editing files, restoring to a previous restore point, repair with installation disk to a full reformat.

Before you do anything complicated, **try a simple reboot**. That fixed it for me.